# JavaScript/jQuery trouble with making a trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I simply want to trigger an element from it's position to another when I click on a button. Then, if I click the button again, I want it to go back where it was.
I have this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.trigger').click(function() {
    $('.trigger').toggle(
         function() {
             $('.mod').css({'margin-left':'0px'});
             },
         function() {
             $('.mod').css({'margin-left':'-100px'});
             }
         );
    });
});
```

When I press the button the element does what I want. But the button disappears. And I am not quite sure, that the element will be triggered back.
Now I just want a working code that can do the job.

Comment: if you could create a fiddle of what you have done, it would be help full for the community to help you. http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html

Comment: Can you show the html of `.trigger` .

Comment: [jQuery's `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) doesn't know what to do with two callbacks. Is your version provided by a plugin? What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.toggle()` is hiding and showing the targeted element, so you need something else. One way is, just to check the `margin-left` of the element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        alert($('.mod').css('margin-left'));
        if($('.mod').css('margin-left') == '0px') {
           $('.mod').css('margin-left', '-10px');
        }
        else {
            $('.mod').css('margin-left', '0px');
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mr8gvk2/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.trigger').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( $(this).hasClass("isLeft") ) {
        $(".mod").stop().css({'margin-left':'0px'});                            
    } else {
        $(".mod").stop().css({'margin-left':'50px'}); //given +50px because it disappears when -50px is given
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("isLeft");
    return false;
    });
});
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e0fe1f9x/)**

Answer (score 0):

IF you're using jQuery 1.9 or later the problem is that the `.toggle()` event handling method was removed from the library.

You can implement your own toggle :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".trigger").click(function() {
  var f = !$(this).data("toggleFlag");
  if (f) {
     $('.mod').css({'margin-left':'0px'});
  } else {
    $('.mod').css({'margin-left':'-100px'});
  }
  $(this).data("toggleFlag", f);
 });
});
```

This uses the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to keep track of a boolean flag to indicate which code to execute.

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/emotcctt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to `toggle`, `.mod` not `.trigger`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.trigger').click(function() {
    $('.mod').toggle(
      function() {
         $('.mod').css({'margin-left':'0px'});
      },
      function() {
         $('.mod').css({'margin-left':'-100px'});
       }
     );
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e0fe1f9x/1/)**